# How to validate Angular fromgroup input based on the value of a 2nd input in the form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `[formGroup]` in Angular version8 app.
I am trying to validate the form based on these simple rules:

1. if a file is uploaded (includes just choosing *any* file with the button) then the Reason input is NOT required, else
2. if a file has not been chosen (ie 'choose file' has no value) then a Reason must be provided for form validation to pass.

File upload is optional if a Reason text is provided.
How do I check inside the Reason textArea that a file has been chosen? I simply can't seem to write a validation statement using that `ngClass`

template:

```
<form [formGroup]="dialogForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lbl-col">
        <label for="reason">Reason<span class="required-star">*</span></label>
    </div>
  <div class="col">
    <textarea
        id="reasonForChange"
        formControlName="reasonForChange"
        name="reasonForChange"
        type="text"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedReasonText"
        [ngClass]="{invalid: dialogForm.get('File').invalid}"
    >
    </textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="lbl-col"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <input
                type="file"
                id="reasonFile"
                formControlName="File"
                (change)="onFileChange($event)"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
[...]
// submit button
<button
  class="primary-button"
  label="update status"
  (click)="update()" // a POST nothing more.
  [disabled]="dialogForm.invalid"
></button>
```

and in my controller:

```
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.dialogForm = this.fb.group({
            chooseStatus: [null, Validators.required],
            reasonForChange: [null, Validators.required],
            File: [null],
        });
```

Using `[ngClass]="{invalid: dialogForm.get('File').invalid}"` or variations of it, it doesn't appear to check `formControlName="File"` but instead checks itself, 'reasonforChange'.

I have also tried the crossValidation template from Ang docs.
Extend the Formbuilder:

```
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) {
        this.dialogForm = this.fb.group({
            chooseStatus: [null],
            reasonForChange: [null],
            File: [null],
        }, {validators: crossFormValidator}
    );
```

and provide

```
export const crossFormValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const reasonForChange = control.get('reasonForChange');
    const file= control.get('File');
    return file && reasonForChange && attachment.value !== '' ? { crossValid: true } : null;
};
```

but that errors on this line in my template

```
    <div *ngIf="dialogForm.errors?.['crossValid'] && (dialogForm.dirty)" class="form-validation-warning">
        <span class="warning-label">* Required</span>
    </div>
```

at `Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 20 in [dialogForm.errors?.['crossValid'] && (dialogForm.dirty)]`
Even though that is taken almost verbatiim from the angular docs at https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-template-driven-forms

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/cross-field-validation-in-angular-588fbfdea96d#:~:text=Angular%20provides%20FormControl%20validation%20in,specifically%20to%20that%20form%20control.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a simple approach for that, to validate different fields in angular.

Create a getter function in .ts file as follow:

```
get If() {
return this.dialogForm.controls;
```

}

This function is returning the controls of each field in the form.

Now, apply this function on the form fields as follow:

```
<form [formGroup]="dialogForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lbl-col">
      <label for="reason">Reason<span class="required-star">*</span></label>
    </div>
  <div class="col" *ngIf="If.File.valid || !If.File.untouched">
   <textarea
      id="reasonForChange"
      formControlName="reasonForChange"
      name="reasonForChange"
      type="text"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedReasonText"
      [ngClass]="{invalid: dialogForm.get('File').invalid}"
      >
    </textarea>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="lbl-col"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <input
            type="file"
            id="reasonFile"
            formControlName="File"
            (change)="onFileChange($event)"
        />
    </div>
   </div>

  // submit button
   <button
     class="primary-button"
     label="update status"
     (click)="update()" // a POST nothing more.
     [disabled]="dialogForm.invalid"
   ></button>
  </form>
```

This way, it is going to work as expected

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, even changing the ngIf to ngClass. Ngif hid the elements, which isn't what I wanted at all.